# Python: How to reduce runtime for four glass/lazy susan algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

This is a homework question to write a function to solve the lazy susan problem, with the help of python files written by my tutor.

Online explanation of the problem:
https://www.interviewchacha.com/puzzles?qid=216

These are some functions given to me.

```
create_table(size)
```

> returns new Table with size number of coins

```
get_table_size(Table)
```

> return number of coins on table

```
check_solved(Table)
```

> returns True if all the coins are facing the same direction,otherwise returns False

```
flip_coins(Table,move=None)
```

> has no return value. Flips coins on table at specified indices in the boolean move tuple,with length corresponding to number of coins on table.Table is spunned randomly

I wrote a function that I would think works(it passed all the tests given in the assignment, however it's rejected as the code took a little too long(5s is considered too long for submission). Can anyone suggest how I can make the algorithm faster?

```
def solve(table):
    p=0
    x=get_table_size(table)
    while not check_solved(table):
        n=(p+1)%x
        if n==0:
        tup=p*(0,)+(1,)
        else:
            tup=p*(0,)+(1,0)+(x-n)*(0,)
        flip_coins(table,tup)
        p=n
```

Test case

```
t16_5 = create_table(16)
solve(t16_5)
print(check_solved(t16_5))
```

Tell me if any more info is needed

Comment: What is the "lazy susan problem"?

Comment: @Henry, sry edited the post since lazy susan might not be a well known name